# JavaScript how to use Document innerText?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<script>

    <%for (String st : photo.keySet()) {%>
        document.getElementById('id').innerText += "\n" + "<%=st%>";
        printGeocode(
            <%=photo.get(st).getX()%>,<%=photo.get(st).getY()%>
        );
    <%}%>
        function printGeocode(x, y) {
            document.getElementById('id').innerText += "\n" + x +" / "+y;
        }

    </script>
```

in my code `'document.getElementById('id').innerText += "\n" + x+"/"+y;'` is work fine

but `document.getElementById('id').innerText += "\n" + "<%=st%>";` is not working

i replace first document innerText to document.write(); it just print just one Text

how to fix this source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about wrap with this?

```
window.onload = function(){
<%for (String st : photo.keySet()) {%>
    document.getElementById('id').innerText += "\n" + "<%=st%>";
    printGeocode(
        <%=photo.get(st).getX()%>,<%=photo.get(st).getY()%>
    );
<%}%>
};
```